# Prove that a conditionally convergent series has an infinity of positive terms and an infinity of negative terms.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The book I am using for my Advance Calculus course is Introduction to Analysis by Arthur Mattuck.

Prove that a conditionally convergent series has an infinity of positive terms and an infinity of negative terms.

This is my rough proof to this question. I was wondering if anybody can look over it and see if I made a mistake or if there is a simpler way of doing this problem. I want to thank you ahead of time it is greatly appreciated.So lets begin.

Proof:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that the sum of two absolutely convergent series is absolutely convergent?

If so, you can work like this. If the series has a finite number of positive terms, change the sign of every term. That does not change the convergence properties - just the sign of every expression. So you can assume, for contradiction, that the series has a finite number of negative terms. Suppose the last of these is term $N$.

Then show that $a_1+a_2+a_3 + \dots + a_N+0+0+0 \dots$ is absolutely convergent as is $0+0+\dots +0+a_{N+1}+a_{N+2}+\dots$ (all the non-zero terms are now positive and the sum is bounded above). Then add them term by term to show that the sum is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing something different than asked in the task.

For the task, you are finished after the claim that both of $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ diverge, since a sum of finitely many terms is always finite.